# Deployment of Web Application on WSO2 EI in Developer Studio

Tags: wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am not getting a way to deployment of war files on WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.2 while running it on Developer Studio.

Comment: Could you be more specific on what you are trying to do here? If it is to deploy the web application in the WSO2 EI, I'm afraid that is not possible. According to the documentation it says, "From WSO2 EI 6.1.0 onwards, it does not ship the functionalities of WSO2 Application Server (AS). However, you can develop applications using MSF4J, JAX-RS or JAX-WS technologies and deploy in WSO2 EI. If you already have applications in WAR or AAR formats, use WSO2 AS 5.3.0 or Tomcat as the server to deploy web apps." (https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI610/About+this+Release)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am agree with @Dinu94. I had to install WSO2 Developer studio 3.8.0 to get it worked with Web application.

Thanks for your reply.